Optimization of Eigenvalue in variable matrix
Given this large, sparse matrix, how can I optimize the values of $a$ and $b$, so that a specific eigenvalue, for example the 6th one (in order) is maximized?
The values of a and b can be chosen from a discrete set, e.g. $a \in \{1,2,3\}$
PS: for those interested, the types or discrete variables for $a$
correspond to atom types in a molecule and $b_i$
specifies a bond characteristic between atom $$
and $i+1$.


since your matrix is sparse, tridiagonal you might be able to formulate the optimization problem directly via the min-max theorem.

Hope this is helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/q/131527/535202
